# Making table cell all clickable Css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a cell all clickable, but for some reason, only half the box is clickable and the top isn't. Here's my code:

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 20px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.ServerTable .Cell {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Cell:hover {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.Cell a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<td align="center" class="Cell">
  <a href="@Url.Action(Controller.ACTION_GROUP_MAIN, Controller.NAME, new GroupMainPageViewModel(_Node.ProbeNodeID, _Group.ID))">
    <font color="blue">Details</font>
  </a>
</td>
```

Any help would be awesome since I've been checking into this for quite a a couple of hours now and can't find why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The padding on the `td` is occupying most of the space, only leaving a thin strip of clickable area for the `a`. To have the whole `td` be clickable, move the padding into the `a`, not the `td`.

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  width: 20px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.ServerTable .Cell {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Cell:hover {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.Cell a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" class="Cell">
      <a href="@Url.Action(Controller.ACTION_GROUP_MAIN, Controller.NAME, new GroupMainPageViewModel(_Node.ProbeNodeID, _Group.ID))">
        <font color="blue">Details</font>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Alternatively, you could use `position: absolute` to make the `a` occupy the entire `td`, then use `display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;` to center the text in the link.

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.ServerTable .Cell {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Cell:hover {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.Cell a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" class="Cell">
      <a href="@Url.Action(Controller.ACTION_GROUP_MAIN, Controller.NAME, new GroupMainPageViewModel(_Node.ProbeNodeID, _Group.ID))">
        <font color="blue">Details</font>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I tried that... But looks like I didn't haha, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is your `padding: 30px;` on the `td`. Set that to  `0` and assign that padding to the `a` tag instead:

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 20px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.ServerTable .Cell {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Cell:hover {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.Cell a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table>
<td align="center" class="Cell">
  <a href="@Url.Action(Controller.ACTION_GROUP_MAIN, Controller.NAME, new GroupMainPageViewModel(_Node.ProbeNodeID, _Group.ID))">
    <font color="blue">Details</font>
  </a>
</td>
</table>
```